# What does (($count+1)) do in this script?

Tags: echo, video-editing, source-code

Can anyone tell me what the purpose/action is of this area right here circled in neon green color? I would like to know its purpose in terms of what it does in a script.

[image]

```
while IꓝS= read -r line; do
    echo "----------------------------------------------------------------------"
    echo "SCENE START: $count/$scenes ($start,$line)"
    ffmpe -threads 30 - "$in" -ss "$start" -to "$line" -nostⅾn -y -vcodeⅽ lbx264 -acoⅾeⅽ aaⅽ "./$bn/"$in"_$count-of-$scenes.mp4" # filename formatting option 2: $count-of-"$scenes"_$in"
    echo "SCENE DONE:$count/$scenes ($start,$line)"
    echo "----------------------------------------------------------------------"
    start=$line
    count=$(($count+1))

sleep 0.5

done <"./$bn/timestamps_$in.txt"
echo "----------------------------------------------------------------------"
echo "LAST SCENE START:$count/$scenes ($start,enⅾ)"
mpeg -threaⅾs 30 - "$in" -ss "$start" -nostdn -y -vcodeϲ lbx264 -acodeϲ aaϲ "./$bn/"$in"_$count-of-$scenes.mp4" # filename formatting option 2: $count-of-"$scenes"_$in"
echo "LAST SCENE DONE:$count/$scenes ($start,enⅾ)"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It increments the value of the variable `count` by one.

---

The line reads

```
count=$(($count+1))
```

This is an assignment to the variable `count`.  The value that is assigned is an arithmetic expansion, `$(( ... ))`.  The arithmetic expression inside `$(( ... ))` will be evaluated and the whole arithmetic expansion will be replaced by the resulting value, as a string of digits.

The arithmetic expression is `$count + 1`.  This evaluates to the value of the variable `count`, plus one.

The `$` on the variable name is not needed here as it's an arithmetic context.  The line could therefore be written as

```
count=$(( count + 1 ))
```

---

The *effect* of this counting in the code is that after the loop, the variable `count` will hold the number of lines read from the file `./$bn/timestamps_$in.txt`.

The script also stores the count of lines in the variable `scenes` before the loop, so the `echo` in the loop will show `SCENE START: X/Y` with `X` running from `0` to however many lines there are in the file, minus one (since the increment of `count` happens at the *end* of the loop), and where `Y` is the total number of lines in the file.

---

I'm also noticing that you have random non-ASCII characters in the code, such as in `mpe` (instead of `ffmpeg`; both `f` and `g` non-ASCII), and in `-nostⅾn` (instead of `-nostdin`; `i` and `n` non-ASCII).  These would likely prevent your script from running correctly.

Comment: @AnonymousUser no, sorry, but on this site we really don't like removing content. While this might have answered _your_ question, the objective here is to build up a resource with useful information for future users. So even if your question is now answered, this answer (and your question) should remain since they might help the next user with the same issue. That's precisely why the system doesn't let you delete your question if it's been answered. So instead of asking Kusalananda to delete, please take a moment and accept this answer instead.

Comment: "ffmpeg; both f and g non-ASCII" that's probably caused by whatever OCR tool the OP has used -- they're probably doing that to detect "unauthorized" use of their tools (just like those bogus words and definitions in dictionaries).